# --Warehouse-dir works but target-dir errors out

Tags: sqoop

Why is `target-dir` not working when `--import-all-tables` is used?

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --warehouse-dir /user/cloudera/retail_db

sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --target-dir /user/cloudera/retail_db
```

Error Log;

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/07/05 06:55:43 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.8.0
17/07/05 06:55:43 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/07/05 06:55:43 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import-all-tables:
17/07/05 06:55:43 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
17/07/05 06:55:43 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /user/cloudera/retail_db
```

Comment: you should add the error information

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Sqoop user guide:
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html

Sqoop by default when issued a import-all-tables command it will import to your current user's hdfs home folder:

ie:
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --target-dir /user/cloudera/

or the below also will work, it will just import  to /user/cloudera/ :

sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera

But in your case you are using a different destination apart from  your home dir, hence --warehouse-dir will be used here:

sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --warehouse-dir /user/cloudera/retail_db